# what is Hybrid inheritance , is it mixture of hierarchical, multiple and multilevel inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Can anyone help me with Hybrid Inheritance. I have seen many tutorials and also researched on google, but still I find it difficult to accept it that it  is just mixture of multiple and multilevel inheritance and not of hierarchical inheritance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "Hybrid inheritance" is not a thing in C++. Whatever tutorial you've seen that talks about it should tell you what it means by that term.

Comment: @Community is correct.

Answer (score -1):

According to Codearchery (the video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VdYat6Yqxs)):

> Hybrid Inheritance is a mix of **any two kinds or more** of inheritance types.

*Syntax of hybrid:*

```
Inheritance type + Inheritance type (or more inheritance type) = hybrid inheritance
```

**Example:**

```
hierarchical inheritance + multilevel inheritance = hybrid inheritance
```

##### OR

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)):

> Hybrid inheritance is when a mix of two or more of the above types of inheritance occurs. An example of this is when class A has a subclass B which has two subclasses, C and D. This is a mixture of both multilevel inheritance and hierarchal inheritance.

Both sources draws a conclusion: **It is a mix of any two kinds of inheritance type.**

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, this is from Codearchery and the video is posted [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VdYat6Yqxs) and the time stamp for this is **0:32**.

Comment: The examples in this video are very bad uses of inheritance, that's for sure. No wonder they came up with their own terms that nobody else uses.